# spark worker running contineuosly giving errors

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark

I have setup cassandra cluster with 2 data centres and 3 nodes each, each data centre has 1 seed node and a replication factor 2. My spark is also setup with 2 worker machines of 2 core and 8 gb ram and a master machine with 4 gb ram. Now I am running spark jobs after every hour and the data it needs to process in this hour is around 20,00,000. My spark job is contineously running showing this error in my worker node

```
15/08/14 03:31:54 INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Suspected host 10.0.1.205 (DC2)
15/08/14 03:32:27 INFO RequestHandler: Query SELECT "addedtime" FROM "sams"."events" WHERE token("appname") > ? AND token("appname") <= ? AND "addedtime" >= ? AND "addedtime" < ?   ALLOW FILTERING is not prepared on /10.0.1.205:9042, preparing before retrying executing. Seeing this message a few times is fine, but seeing it a lot may be source of performance problems


 ERROR Session: Error creating pool to /10.0.1.205:9042
com.datastax.driver.core.ConnectionException: [/10.0.1.205:9042] Unexpected error during transport initialization (com.datastax.driver.core.OperationTimedOutException: [/10.0.1.205:9042] Operation timed out)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.initializeTransport(Connection.java:186)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:116)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.PooledConnection.<init>(PooledConnection.java:32)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:586)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SingleConnectionPool.<init>(SingleConnectionPool.java:76)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool.newInstance(HostConnectionPool.java:35)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$2.call(SessionManager.java:231)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$2.call(SessionManager.java:224)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.OperationTimedOutException: [/10.0.1.205:9042] Operation timed out
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Future.onTimeout(Connection.java:917)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$ResponseHandler$1.run(Connection.java:981)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:546)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.notifyExpiredTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:446)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:395)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        ... 1 more
```

Can you please let me know what can be the issue.
Here are the options with which I am running spark jobs

```
--conf spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb=67108864
 --executor-memory 6G
--driver-memory 6G
```

Adding my table scehma

```
CREATE TABLE events (
 addedtime timestamp,
 appname text,
 hostname text,
 assetname text,
 brandname text,
 eventname text,
 eventorigin text,
 eventtime timestamp,
 PRIMARY KEY ((appname), addedtime, hostname)
);
```

My appname is the partition key and addedtime and hostname are part of clustering keys.

Comment: Can you share your spark code? How you are connecting to spark (using java-driver or spark-cassandra-connection) ? Is you providing host name in your spark appliction?

Answer (score 0):

spark.cassandra.query.retry.delay

spark.cassandra.read.timeout_ms

spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb

spark.cassandra.input.fetch.size_in_rows

thwese you have to set in SparkConf .

Comment: can u let me know the default values and what is the optimum values of these for large data (1000 req/s)

Comment: default values is 100 and optimum value is depend upon no. of worker of spark . you have to find out optimum value by testing .